# Doctrine DQL update andWhere( 'DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d" ) = ?', '2013-08-09 12:24:09')

Tags: doctrine, date-format

I have problem with updating rows , date format in db is: Y-m-d H:i:s

```
$date ='2013-08-09';// from POST

Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->update( 'column z2ud' )
  ->set( array( 'z2ud.column' => 'value' ) )//
  ->where( 'z2ud.column = ?', 'value' )
  ->andWhere( 'DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d" ) = ?', $date)
  ->execute();
```

SQL returns: `Unknown aggregate alias: "%Y-%m-%d"`

Comment: What kind of data type did you chose to store your dates?

Comment: Yes, I see now someone changed the type to timestamp Thx, I will try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED :    You must use \'%Y-%m-%d\' not ->  "%Y-%m-%d"